# Jquery hover lock up

Tags: jquery, hover

This imageswitch fade animation locks up sometimes when mousing out and leaves the 'facebookblue.png' in place until the next mouseover?

```
$("#facebookrollover").hover(function(){  
   $("#facebookimg").stop(true, true).ImageSwitch({NewImage:"facebookblue.png",  Speed:200});
},
function(){
   $("#facebookimg").stop(true, true).ImageSwitch({NewImage:"facebookgrey.png", Speed:400});
 });
```

And the html part:

```
<a id="facebookrollover" href="http://www.facebook.com"><img id="facebookimg" src="facebookgrey.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>
```

Oh and I'm using the imageswitch jquery plugin, but I doubt that that is the problem, since I get same problem when just changing the opacity.

Comment: I guess ImageSwitch is the cause of this. You should file a bug to the [author](http://www.hieu.co.uk/blog/index.php/imageswitch/), and hopefully he can get it fixed. Sadly, jsFiddle is down, otherwise I'd create a switcher for you :)

Comment: why not changing the value of the src attribute with simple jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with only css: place two `img` tags inside `a` one hidden by default, and switch therir `display` property on `:hover`. Or even better combine them in sprite and just change background-position.

Comment: Would this animate it though?

Comment: sorry, the speed part was off. You could do css animations, but this will work only in modern browsers.